# Integral of symmetric functions $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

That is my problem...
$f$ is decreasing, continuous, $f:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]$, 
$f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ [Symmetric function]
and I have some marginal conditions like $f(x,1)=f(1,x)=0$.

Is it possible to compute the double integral $\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 f(x,y)dxdy$ using some marginal integration?

For example, when is this true?
$$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^1 f(x,y)dxdy= \left[\int_{0}^1 f(z,a)dz\right]^2,$$ for some value $a \in [0,1]$.

ex: $f(x,y)=(1-x)(1-y)$ my statement is true, using $a=0$.

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you understand by `decreasing` for a  multivariable function?

Comment: Hi TZ,
Thanks for asking! 
In my problem,it is just marginal decreasing... 
I mean, for each y* (fixed), 
f(x,y*) is decreasing in x.
Also this happens for other coordinate.
Thanks!
D